# VS 2012 cmdlet remote debug doesn't stop at breakpoint

Tags: c#, debugging, powershell, visual-studio-2012

I write a cmdlet for Exchange 2010 management. So I need to debug it on Exchange 2010 server. 
I have an Exchange 2010 started on virtual machine (the one I have VS2012 on).

My debug is planned like this. As post-build operation I set following:

```
cmd.exe /c copy $(TargetPath) \\test-exch2010-1\c$\temp /y
```

As run command I set following:

```
Start external command: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Command line arguments: -NoExit -Command "Import-Module C:\Temp\ExchMgmt.dll"
```

When I run the project the Powershell with proper command runs on the target server. But when I run the cmdlet no breakpoint is hit at all.

If I build project in same way but then run Powershell on the target server manually, import module and then attach VS2012 to the powershell.exe process all breakpoints are successfully hit. Though sometimes same issue happens.

The Exch2010 server is in domain, the VS2012 computer isn't. I use the only account in domain to connect, which is adminstrator of everything :-) Additionally I've given explicit permission to this user to debug programs in SecPol.

Additionally I tried to debug this project is VS2010. There I'm getting a message: "The following module was built either with optimizations enabled or without debug information". 
I double-checked the project settings:
  - Optimize code is disabled
  - Debug info is full
  - PDB file is generated

I digged through the similar topics and found out that disabling of Just My Code setting helps. I tried this but it didn't help in my case

I've noticed the warning that System.Data.dll has different platform target (I use x64. That  could be a reason). Since I didn't use this assembly I removed it from the list of references. After that I've noticed no changes when I run the project. But when I attach debugger to the running powershell.exe process on remote computer with loaded my module I see Debug log stating following:

```
'powershell.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\temp\ExchMgmt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

However I ensure I copy both DLL and PDB files to the remote computer.
I checked loaded modules (Debug -> Windows -> Modules) and found out my module is loaded with no debug symbols. When I opened Symbol Load Information window I've found following entry:

```
d:\Projects\ExchMgmt\ExchMgmt\obj\x64\Debug\ExchMgmt.pdb: PDB does not match image.
```

I've checked the powershell.exe process is x64. But I also noticed it states the CLR is 2.0.50727. Not sure if it's correct because the target framework for my module is 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was proposed a solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/154c879b-2078-4e32-9bb6-b43d2d4b435c/vs-2012-cmdlet-remote-debug-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoint?forum=vsdebug&prof=required)

- create a powershell.exe.config file next powershell.exe in the C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ directory
- Assuming one doesn't exist already, set the contents to be 

  `<?xml version ="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
    <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" /> 
      <!-- where 2.0.50727 is the version I read above, tweak if necessary -->
    </startup>
  </configuration>`

I set first version 3.5, which I expected to match built assembly. But then I get an error in VS2012 that powershell.exe platform is newer than one VS2012 runs. So I set it to 2.0.50727 and now it works fine :-)